# Understanding C# code mechanics

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and in my text book it ask me to add some code to the main method of the Program.cs class, but does not show me how. I am a beginner, so I am just looking for the basics and as I go forth, I will pick up the more advanced lessons so please, keep your explanations thorough, but down to a day 1 level. The following is the code I have provided. It continuously provide me with errors<

Here is the code below:  I am supposed to add the public static voice TestIfElse method to the Program.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ifelse_Statement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestIfElse(10);
            public static void TestIfElse(int n)
            {
                if (n < 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 10”);
                }
                else if (n < 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 20”);
                }
                else if (n < 30)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 30”);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(“n is greater than or equal to 30”);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is simple - you can't have nested functions in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ifelse_Statement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestIfElse(10);
        }
        public static void TestIfElse(int n)
        {
            if (n < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 10”);
            }
            else if (n < 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 20”);
            }
            else if (n < 30)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 30”);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“n is greater than or equal to 30”);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the body of the TestIfElse method outside the body of the Main method. That way they are both considered methods of the class, and will work as desired.

Also, in your logic, you need to check for ranges i.e. a number less than 20 is also less than 30, so you probably want to check if a number is between 10 and 20, or 20 and 30 and so on.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestIfElse(10);
    }

public static void TestIfElse(int n)
{
    if (n < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 10”);
    }
    else if (n < 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 20”);
    }
    else if (n < 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“n is less than 30”);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“n is greater than or equal to 30”);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ClassHere is the basic structure of a class

```
public class MyClass // this is the declaration of the class 
{
    // this is a property, it is accessible by things outside of this class.
    public static string MyProperty { get; set; } ;
    private static string _myField; // this is a ['private] field, it is intended to store the state of the object. it cannot be accessed from outside of this class

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // this is the method that gets run first so it make all of your initial calls
    }

    public static void TestIfElse(int n)
    {
        // this is another method (taught as module, operation, action, or subroutine in schools)
        // it has return type of void which is more or less "nothing". This type of behavior simply does 
        // something but doesn't return a value
    }

    public static bool IsNotPrime(int input)
    {
        // this is an actual function in that will return a single value whether its a primitive value or an
        // object. Whatever it is, there's ONE. The point is that a call to this function is now synonymous with
        // the value it returns. So for example, if this method was real, it is equivalent to 'true' so you could 
        // actually say if(IsNotPrime(8)){ // do things }
        return input % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

you must keep these methods separate. Classes can have many members (fields, properties, methods, etc), one method can call another, but on method cannot contain another. So when you're learning to recognize these, if you see keywords such as public or static, you should be thinking that these need to be their own entities inside of the class but outside of other class members.

For example, other than the class declaration itself, `private` or `private static` (or any other access modifier) before a type and identifier are the first things you see when declaring a class method, so don't attempt to put anything else like that inside of that member.

The problem that you're having with your code is mostly about the declaration of `TestIfElse`. You have it declared inside of the main function which you cannot do. Move it outside of main and you should be fine.